# Memory leak in the following C code

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

For the following sample of code there is memory leak. How can we prevent memory leak in the following case:

```
            1 #include <stdio.h>
            2 #include <stdlib.h>
            3 
            4 typedef struct sample_help {
            5 int *value;
            6 void **pointers;
            7 }*sample,sample_node;
            8 
            9 
            10 sample main(){
            11 sample  ABC=NULL; 
            12 sample  XYZ=NULL;
            13 sample  kanchi = NULL;
            14 
            15 ABC = malloc(sizeof(sample_node));
            16 XYZ = malloc(sizeof(sample_node));
            17 ABC->pointers = malloc(5*sizeof(void *));
            18 XYZ->pointers = malloc(5*sizeof(void *));
            19 ABC->value = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
            20 XYZ->value = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
            21 
            22 ABC->value[0] = 10;
            23 ABC->value[1] = 20;
            24 
            25 XYZ->pointers[0] = ABC;
            26 kanchi = XYZ->pointers[0];
            27 
            28 printf("::::%d\n",XYZ->pointers[0]);
            29 printf("kanchi1:::::%d\n",kanchi->value[0]);
            30 
            31 
            32 return XYZ;
            33 }
            34
```

Following is the output of valgrind.

```
==27448== 
==27448== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27448==     in use at exit: 152 bytes in 6 blocks 
==27448==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 0 frees, 152 bytes allocated
==27448== 
==27448== 152 (16 direct, 136 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss  record 6 of 6
==27448==    at 0x4C244E8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==27448==    by 0x40056B: main (test2.c:16)
==27448== 
==27448== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27448==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==27448==    indirectly lost: 136 bytes in 5 blocks
==27448==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27448==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27448==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==27448==
```

Comment: ...by freeing allocated memory.

Comment: **sample**  is the type i would like to return in place of **int**

Comment: @thetna Are you sure that's legal?

Comment: You're doing 4 mallocs, where's the 4 deallocations?

Comment: @Mitch , if a free the allocated memory, i would not be able to return the value if **XYZ**. Can you please let me know how can I overcome this situation?

Comment: I freed the **ABC**, once i free it , the value assigned to **XYZ** were lost.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do ? Why do you think you want to return a data structure from `main()` ?

Comment: @quasiverse, it should legal , since **void main()** is legal, then ofcouse the above case should be legal.

Comment: @thetna ... your logic is *really* badly broken.

Comment: @Paul R, actually this is the prototype of my real function. So as to compile and test i used main instead of my other real function. Please you may take it as some other module except for **main** that returns structure.

Comment: @thetna To clarify on broken logic, it's like saying 0 squared is 0 and 1 squared is 1 so therefore, any number squared is itself.

Comment: @thetna: OK - in that case you should implement this is a proper function and then call it from main if you want to test it.

Comment: @Paul R, I have implemented similar functions in my real project. And in the real project also I am getting the error the way it is appearing in this code.

Comment: @thetna: see my answer below for how to (a) implement this properly (without abusing main()) and (b) how to free the memory in the caller when you're done.

Comment: @Paul R, thanks for the code. Will try the same.

Comment: @Paul R, Actually, i am implementing the database, I think your code empties my entries. Is it possible me to use for future use? I mean , if i keep the data strucuted, then i may use those data for future searching or some thing like that.

Comment: @thetna: yes, the whole point of the example is that you can use the data structure after the call to your function and then free it later *when you're done with it*. The line with the comment that says "`// ... do something with the data structure xyz ...` represents the part of your program that actually does something useful with the data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should really be more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct sample_help {
    int *value;
    void **pointers;
} *sample, sample_node;

sample foo(void)
{
    sample  ABC=NULL;
    sample  XYZ=NULL;
    sample  kanchi = NULL;

    ABC = malloc(sizeof(sample_node));
    XYZ = malloc(sizeof(sample_node));
    ABC->pointers = malloc(5*sizeof(void *));
    XYZ->pointers = malloc(5*sizeof(void *));
    ABC->value = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    XYZ->value = malloc(5*sizeof(int));

    ABC->value[0] = 10;
    ABC->value[1] = 20;

    XYZ->pointers[0] = ABC;
    kanchi = XYZ->pointers[0];

    printf("::::%d\n",XYZ->pointers[0]);
    printf("kanchi1:::::%d\n",kanchi->value[0]);

    return XYZ;
}

int main(void)
{
    // call your function
    sample xyz = foo();

    // ... do something with the data structure xyz ...

    // free memory allocated by your function
    free(xyz->pointers[0]->value);    // free ABC->value
    free(xyz->pointers[0]->pointers); // free ABC->pointers
    free(xyz->pointers[0]);           // free ABC
    free(xyz->value);                 // free XYZ->value
    free(xyz->pointers);              // free XYZ->pointers
    free(xyz);                        // free XYZ

    return 0;
}
```

Note that we free the data structure from within main() after we're done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Just free the used memory when it's no longer needed:

```
free(ABC->value);
free(XYZ->value);
free(ABC->pointers);
free(XYZ->pointers);
free(ABC);
free(XYZ);
```

Btw: When this is the whole program, it wouldn't actually matter. Since the OS reclaims all unfreed memory when a process is ended, memory that is in use until the termination of the programm is not required to be freed. However, it is good practice.

Comment: With `sample main()` we know there is no OS :P

Comment: If i free **XYZ** then how can I return the strucutre?I want to return the **XYZ** with the **ABC** assigned in the **pointers** of **XYZ**.Lets take an analogy that , a node is added in the root node.

Comment: The caller of main() in this case needs to free the memory after using the values. It is very odd to use main() in this way, can you describe more about the wider context of what you are doing?

Comment: You never know when someone else will take your code (even you, 6 months later) and move it around without reviewing it. Consider for example renaming this main() function so it can be used in a deeper program. Because of that potential (even though small), I don't consider proper memory management to merely be "good practice", I consider it to be a solid requirement.

Comment: Don't free XYZ, return a pointer to it and the function which receives it then is responsible for freeing it later.

Comment: @Vickey, I have added it in the questions comment. Please refer there. I am implementing a data-base where children nodes gets keep on adding in the parent node. For it, i need to create a child node allocating memory. I am doing similar in my real code. And I am getting the memory error, the way i am getting here.

Answer (score 2):

Having now read your update in the comments, your module (*not* called main()) that allocates and returns the memory is fine.

Whatever module uses the value returned from your module, needs to free the data after use. So if you implement your module as

```
sample mymodule(void)
{
    sample foo = malloc(10);
    /* set up contents of foo as required */
    return foo;
}
```

Then the caller of mymodule would go like this:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sample bar = mymodule();
    /* use contents of bar as required */
    free(bar);
    return 0;
}
```